# Select particular Foreign key from one django model choice session to another model

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to do a django practice and while doing I tried to add a foreign key to one model to another model.
I have a model called "Employee_detail" and it have a session called "Position".
Position is a choice field and the choices are 'Manager', 'Supervisor' and 'Employee'.

I have another model called "Department" and I used OneToOneField to get the Employee details(Manager) in this model. I wanted to add the department manager(only) to "Dept_Manager" field.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    Dept_No = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6)
    Dept_Name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    Dept_Manager = models.OneToOneField('Employee_Detail', models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Dept_No

class Employee_Detail(models.Model):
    Employee_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6)
    Employee_Name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    Primary_Phone = models.IntegerField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    p = (
        ("Manager","Manager"),("Supervisor","Supervisor"),("Employee","Employee")
    )
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices= p, default="Employee")
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Employee_Name)
```

But when I try to do it like this (please check the image blow) in the "Dept_Manager" it is showing and allowing to add "Supervisor" or "Employee" in that field.
I want it to show only the Managers name as options.
Can anyone tell me how to implement that please?

[image: Check this image please]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` both accept the parameter [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to), this will filter the options that can be chosen for the field

```
Dept_Manager = models.OneToOneField(
    'Employee_Detail',
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    limit_choices_to={'Position': 'Manager'}
)
```